# Generate C# class from XSD sitemap with images

Tags: c#, xml, image, sitemap

Could somebody help me generate C# class from XSD(sitemap **with images**)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
   <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
 </url> 
</urlset>
```

**Here is my classes that were generated by xsd.exe tool:**

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true,
        Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
        IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class urlset
    {

        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

        private List<tUrl> urlField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
        {
            get { return this.anyField; }
            set { this.anyField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("url")]
        public List<tUrl> url
        {
            get { return this.urlField; }
            set { this.urlField = value; }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
    public partial class tUrl
    {

        private string locField;

        private string lastmodField;

        private tChangeFreq changefreqField;

        private bool changefreqFieldSpecified;

        private decimal priorityField;

        private bool priorityFieldSpecified;

        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string loc
        {
            get { return this.locField; }
            set { this.locField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string lastmod
        {
            get { return this.lastmodField; }
            set { this.lastmodField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public tChangeFreq changefreq
        {
            get { return this.changefreqField; }
            set { this.changefreqField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool changefreqSpecified
        {
            get { return this.changefreqFieldSpecified; }
            set { this.changefreqFieldSpecified = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal priority
        {
            get { return this.priorityField; }
            set { this.priorityField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool prioritySpecified
        {
            get { return this.priorityFieldSpecified; }
            set { this.priorityFieldSpecified = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
        {
            get { return this.anyField; }
            set { this.anyField = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "image", Type = typeof(image))]
        public List<image> Images { get; set; }

    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
    public enum tChangeFreq
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        always,

        /// <remarks/>
        hourly,

        /// <remarks/>
        daily,

        /// <remarks/>
        weekly,

        /// <remarks/>
        monthly,

        /// <remarks/>
        yearly,

        /// <remarks/>
        never,
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true,
        Namespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1",
        IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class image
    {

        private string locField;

        private string captionField;

        private string geo_locationField;

        private string titleField;

        private string licenseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "loc", DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string loc
        {
            get { return this.locField; }
            set { this.locField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string caption
        {
            get { return this.captionField; }
            set { this.captionField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string geo_location
        {
            get { return this.geo_locationField; }
            set { this.geo_locationField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string title
        {
            get { return this.titleField; }
            set { this.titleField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string license
        {
            get { return this.licenseField; }
            set { this.licenseField = value; }
        }
    }
```

But I have **problem with prefix 'image:'**, I could not sort out how to add this prefix to serialized xml. If I modify Element name by adding semicolon, then it **do escape 'image_x003A_image'**

Answer (score 0):

I also used the xsd.exe tool and had the same issue.  I resolved it as follows:

In the `urlset` class, add the following `[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]` property and create a constructor that adds the "image" xml namespace:

```
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();


  public urlset()
    {
        xmlns.Add("image", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1");
    }
```

In my case I only needed a single image, so I added the following attribute to my image property in `tUrl`

```
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")]
    public image image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.imageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.imageField = value;
        }
    }
```

This then added the "image:" prefix to all my image elements.  You should be able to do something similar for you image list to associate it with the namespace you created above.

This post seems a little old, but hope this helps someone experiencing similar headaches trying to utilize the image sitemap schema extension.